# Unsupported python packages in a virtual env

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

How can I list out the packages in my virtual env which do not support a particular version of Python. If I am updating my python version, I want to list out the packages that do not support that version of Python

Comment: Don't update the Python version. Use `pip freeze` to get a list of currently installed packages, and use that (replace the hard-coded version numbers with lower bounds or remove version constraints altogether) to create a new virtual environment.

Comment: If you really want to check this you can automate the process by looking for each package the required python version: (for example numpy) `https://pypi.org/pypi/numpy/json` and lookup the version you have in the releases to see if it's compatible with the target python you want: (for example the release `1.20.0`  `"requires_python": ">=3.7"` . Should be pretty simple to automate for all the packages you have with `pip freeze`